# Easiest way to find MAC address of a device

Tags: networking, mac-address

We have installed a bunch of medical devices to a location and now we need to activate their network function. Device has an embedded OS (unknown) and only shows its IP address on its network menu once connected to a network.

On this location I have to provide MAC addresses of the devices in order to join them to the network. Manufacturer says only way to see the MAC address is to connect it to network and use ARP command or check through the network.

What would be the fastest way to see the MAC address of this device without connecting it to the network on this location?

I am considering getting a ethernet enabled mobile modem to resolve this but if there is an easier way it would be very helpful.

Comment: No physical serial number or MAC address on the device? If there's just a serial number, can the manufacturer get the MAC address from their system?

Comment: Unfortunately no, they said only way was to use arp command on a windows machine connected to same network.

Comment: I think they're fobbing you off. All medical devices will need to be calibrated, so will have a serial number that NIST-compliant facility will use in their calibration records. The vendor should have all the details on file, sounds like they can't be bothered to go find the information you require.

Comment: Can't you connect the device to a local computer in order to use `arp`?

Comment: @spikey_richie you are probably right but this is time-sensitive and they are what they are (reason not to always go with the cheapest option i guess).

Comment: @harrymc i tried direct connection but all i got was ff:ff:ff:ff:ff as mac address, will try with an LTE modem hoping that works.

Comment: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is broadcast address, typically used for ARP. The device is looking for something or announcing itself. You might need a DHCP server in your local network for it to get an IP and join into.

Answer (score 1):

ARP is your friend. Every device (even without an IP) is sending ARP broadcasts. Your device will save these in an ARP table.

Connect a Windows or Linux device via Ethernet to the device and run

```
arp -a
```

in the terminal/cmd. This lists all the devices, with their respective MAC-Adresses

You can connect the device with just one cable directly to your windows/linux workstation

Links:

- https://www.networkworld.com/article/2750342/checking-your-arp-entries.html

Comment: There's here a chicken-egg problem: The MAC address is required to allow the device on the network, but without it joining the network `arp` can't help. Your answer does not address the poster's problem.

Comment: @harrymc no, the device only needs to be connected through an Ethernet cable. It doesn't need an IP address for that. So the MAC address is not needed. Just plug the cable into the device and the other end into the windows/linux workstation :)

Comment: Hi thanks for this help unfortunately when i tried direct connection with this particular device all i got was ff:ff:ff:ff:ff as mac address. When i tried a printer to check though it worked. I guess this particular device is just not willing to cooperate with me.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand it correctly: in order to get the device into the network you need it’s MAC-address, and in order to get the MAC-address it needs to be in a network, right? So the only option I can come up with is to use a different network to the one you want to put it into, like your phone’s mobile hotspot. Connect the device to your phone or any other WiFi broadcasting device, many laptops can do that as well, get the information you need and then configure the primary network to allow the now known MAC-address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is what i am planning as this particular device only has ethernet for connection i ordered a lte modem with ethernet port. Hopefuly it will allow me to get this done.

Comment: Then I would recommend to use a cross over cable and your laptop. That is probably cheaper and easier to use than an LTE modem.

Answer (score 1):

Start up a linux box, and plug it and your mystery machine back to back with ethernet.  (You can also connect them through a  small switch, but the switch should not be connected to the rest of your network).
Then run the command **ip link show**

```
mint@mint:~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:ac:c0:95:99:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This shows two interfaces:
lo (localhost interface 'lo' which should be ignored), and the ethernet interface -- in this case *enp63s0*.  If you are on a laptop you are also likely to see a wireless interface, often starting  it's name with a name with a 'wl'

The next line starts up tcpdump to listen for arp or bootp (DHCP) packets. **sudo tcpdump -i *enp63s0* arp or port bootps**
(with *enp63s0* being replaced with the ethernet port name you got from the 'ip' output)

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo tcpdump -i enp63s0  arp  or  port bootps
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp63s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:44:52.975293 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 78:ac:c0:95:99:02 (oui Unknown), length 282
00:44:54.008963 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:15:b7:9c:12:e9 (oui Unknown), length 282
00:45:09.351543 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 78:ac:c0:95:99:02 (oui Unknown), length 282
00:45:10.071609 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:15:b7:9c:12:e9 (oui Unknown), length 282
^C
4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
mint@mint:~$
```

Notice that  you see requests from two different addresses.  One is the same as you see on the interface you're listening on (in this case, wlp63s0 = 78:ac:c0:95:99:02 ) the other is the address you're looking for (in this case, 00:15:b7:9c:12:e9)
Once you have the MAC address, you can just unplug this machine and plug in the next machine  you want the address of..

Your linux machine does not need to be a dedicated box.  This was tested using a machine booted from a live DVD ([linux mint 20.3](https://linuxmint.com/download.php) )

Answer (score 0):

If you can plug directly into the device, you can use tcpdump or wireshark to monitor the traffic.  Part of the traffic will be its MAC address.

If you can setup a DHCP server, when it hands out an IP it should record its MAC address.

Some DHCP servers you have to view a log file.

Raspberry Pi has

```
dhcp-lease-list
```

It will list the IP and MAC address.